# Find the missing object

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

**1.** [image]

**2.** [image]

**3.** [image]

**4.** [image]

**5.** [image]

**6.** **?**

**7.**  [image]

**Find the missing object (No. 6)**

> **Note:The first one to post an object with the matching criteria will be the winner.**

> **Hint1: Someone who doesn't know the name of any of these objects too can find the correct answer.**

> **Hint2: The newly added tag is a hint**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the missing image can well be satisfied by the one below

> [image]

The explanation:

> In each image, if we calculate the number of straight edges, we get 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ?, 8. This looks very much like a Fibonacci sequence, with the sixth object requiring 5 edges. And I chose the most famous five sided object, the Pentagon.

Interestingly, [Dyrandz Famador](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20477/12700) could have had this one, if he only chose a different object whose name started with the letter 'P'. :-P

Comment: Perfect. And also the same object that I had in my mind. :)

Answer (score 4):

> 6. PENCIL ?
>  [image]

I based it on the first letter of their name :) which results a pattern of `S` & `P`

1. S - smile
2. P - protractor
3. S - stick
4. P - PIZZA PIE
5. S - [set-square?](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_triangular_instrument_like_a_protractor_called)
6. P -? (**PENCIL**)
7. S - Shuriken ( *thanks to @Anachor* )

Comment: The last one is a surikan or a ninja-star which appear frequently in anime culture. Seems to confirm to your sp pattern.

Comment: +1. But not correct. There is a better fit than this one. The correct answer will fit the pattern More appropriate than simple first letter connection of words. More specifically, someone who doesn't know what a protractor is or a setsquare is, can answer it. Check the updated question for the Hint.

Answer (score 3):

[Inverted setsquare]

[image]

As per my observation the image patterns are in pairs, as in 
1-2 semicircle are inverted
3-4 thickness reduces in opposite direction
5-6 triangle and semicircle should be inverted
7 itself has complements

Answer (score 3):

My answer is...

> [image]

Why? Well...

> Each image represents a different type of angle. 1 is a full revolution, 2 is a straight angle (180 degrees), 3 is no angle (0 degrees), 4 is an acute angle, 5 is a right angle, and 7 is a reflex angle. That leaves only an **obtuse** angle, which this fan represents.

Comment: This makes the most sense, but 7 could just be an obtuse angle really.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah - Somewhat true, but the other angles are within the object, whereas the obtuse angle in 7 is outside the object.